# Differentiate a vector-valued function means to differentiate each of the components separately

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

If we have $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m} $.
We can write $f$ in terms of its components $f = (f_1, f_2, ..., f_m)$

We want to calculate the $partial \, derivative$ with respect to the $j^{th}$ component of the variable $x$ at the point $x_0$ ($i.e.$ calculate $\frac {\partial f} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)$)

It is said that (by Terence Tao in his book Analysis 2, chapter 6.3), to differentiate a vector-valued function one just has to differentiate
each of the components separately.

$i.e. \qquad $ $\frac {\partial f} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)$ = ($\frac {\partial {f_1}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)$, $\frac {\partial {f_2}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)$, ..., $\frac {\partial {f_m}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)$)

I have tried to prove this statement but failed to have any progress. Could you please give me a suggestion for a rigorous proof of this statement ?

Comment: This follows more or less from the fact that a sequence in $\Bbb R^m$ converges to some point iff all the components of the sequence converge to the corresponding component of that point.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0)&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+te_j)-f(x_0)}{t}\\&=\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_1(x_0+te_j)-f_1(x_0)}{t},\dots,\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_m(x_0+te_j)-f_m(x_0)}{t}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac {\partial {f_1}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0), \frac {\partial {f_2}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0), ..., \frac {\partial {f_m}} {\partial {x_j}} (x_0)\right)  
\end{align*}
In the second equality I used the fact that a limit in $\Bbb R^m$ may be computed componentwise.